# Best practice on where to place the hidden div elements on html code

Tags: jquery, html

This is a best practice question. I am working on a HTML template in which I want to appear/disappear div elements based on user interaction. 
I use JQuery for that and everything works ok.

Adding to the divs I need to hide:

```
style="display: none;"
```

works nicely and it doesn't add any additional empty lines when the div is hidden.

My question is where is the best place to place all these hidden divs. Right now I place all of them just before the end of my  element.

Then I append them accordingly to corresponding parent divs.

Ofcource I could place the whole div in quotes and put it in the append function as:

```
$("#_panel_msg").append('<br><i> Downloading excel file with settlements..</i><br>');
```

But this causes readability issues and doesn't look nice in the code.

What would be a good practice for this?

Comment: `</br>` is not valid.... should be `<br>` or `<br/>`

Comment: Think in impaired people, the content of the div need a specific possition to maintain the meaning of the rest?

Comment: The best way is to keep your markup as it should be presented. The only work you should get done via scripting is to hide/show these elements accordingly. Sometimes you can even achieve this via just `CSS`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would place them where you want them to actually appear, but obviously have them hidden initially (like you have got now). Then use show/hide methods to display them, rather than appending them:

```
<div id="myDiv" style="display:none">Contents</div>
```

...
Then when you want to display it:

```
$("#myDiv").show();
```

And to hide it again:

```
$("#myDiv").hide();
```